# Unknown object type error when creating SEQUENCE object

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a Sequence in SQL Server 2012 but I get this error:

> Unknown object type 'SEQUENCE' used in a CREATE, DROP, or ALTER
>   statement.

And I don't see anything called Sequences under the Programmability folder for my database.

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server 2012? You might have Management Studio 2012 but you may be connected to a downlevel server. What does `SELECT @@VERSION;` yield?

Comment: interesting in the help/about section i see  

Sql Server 2012
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML 3.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16443
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.30319.17626
Operating System 6.1.7601                                                         

But select @@version gets this:

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP1) - 10.0.2531.0 (X64) 
 Mar 29 2009 10:11:52 
 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: What you see in about is your client tools. You are obviously connected to a SQL Server 2008.

Comment: but this db is in my local machine in the account created by sql server 2012 the installation wizard

Comment: Regardless, you are connected to a SQL Server 2008 instance.  Even if you installed SQL Server 2012, check to make sure your are connecting to the right instance that you think is 2012.

Answer (score 3):

What is the output when running the following?

```
USE yourDB
GO
SELECT @@version, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases Where DB_NAME() = name
```

It should be `110` and `Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.XXXXXX`